# addEventListener = function in method not working

Tags: javascript

i have problem with window.addEventListener.

***THIS*** works:

```
const engine = {
    eventListeners:function(){
        window.addEventListener("resize",this.resize);
    },
    resize:function(){alert("dupa");},
}
engine.eventListeners();
```

***BUT THIS***: doesn't:

```
const engine = {
    eventListeners:function(){
        window.addEventListener("resize",this.event.resize);
    },
    event:function(){
        function resize(){alert("d");}
    },
}
engine.eventListeners();
```

I dont know why becouse for me it should works.

***I must use `event();`60 times per second and inside event(); will be more functions***

0 errors in console.

Comment: In a second example resize is a private function of an event function. You can't call it from the outside.

Comment: How can i make it public?

Comment: Since `engine.event` is a function, you can't call `resize` as an object, you'd need to call it like `this.event().resize`, which also needs to return the `resize` function.

Comment: @WiktorJanecki you need to put it out of that function

Comment: @jank you should not use the term `private` here, but `scope`. The function `resize` is defined in the **scope** of the anonymous function stored in the property `event`

Comment: So I cant call method's function from global ?

Comment: Really, the issue you're having is that you're trying to access the `resize` function by accessing it from the `event` property... The `resize` function is in the scope of the `event` function, so unless you return the `resize` function and use that return statement to pass it as your event handler, it won't work

Comment: `I must use event();60 times per second` this does not make any sense at all. How is `60 times per second` related to the given code or to the answers?  It can be called as many times as the performance of the PC allows.

Comment: @t.niese for example I can return only one function so It can't works with 2 or 3 etc.

Comment: @t.niese someone says that I should use object instead event function but i cant use all of function in object in one line. Then instead ```engine.event(); ``` i must ``` engine.event.foo(); engine.event.anoterfunc();``` etc.

Comment: I didn't ask about the `and inside event(); will be more functions`, I asked about the `I must use event();60 times per second`. How are the `60 times per second` relevant to the problem of accessibility of the function?

Comment: But if you don't want to call the function _in_ `event` individually, but always at the same time, then why do you talk about `window.addEventListener("resize",this.event.resize);` in your question, and why don't you say `window.addEventListener("resize",this.event)`. `this.event.resize` implies that you want to call them individually.

Comment: But stil i cant use your answer  "someone says that I should use object instead event function but i cant use all of function in object in one line. Then instead engine.event(); i must ``` engine.event.foo(); engine.event.anoterfunc();``` etc."

Comment: @t.niese becouse i dont want to use keyboard function when someone resize my page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code:

```js
const engine = {
    eventListeners:function(){
        window.addEventListener("resize",this.event.resize);
    },
    event:function(){
        function resize(){alert("d");}
    }
}
```

the `resize` function is defined within the scope of the anonymous function that you store in the `event` property and as of that `resize` can only be accessed from within that scope.

But you  probably want to use an object for `event` instead of a function:

```js
const engine = {
    eventListeners:function(){
        window.addEventListener("resize",this.event.resize);
    },
    event: {
        resize : function(){alert("d");}
    }
}
engine.eventListeners();
```

That way you can access it using `this.event.resize`.

Comment: but i must use event func 60 times per second

Comment: @WiktorJanecki `but i must use event func 60 times per second` how is that related to the answer/question?

Comment: @WiktorJanecki and why exactly should the shown code in this answer not fulfill that requirement? You can add more functions like: `event: { resize : function(){alert("d");}, foo : function(){alert("d");}, bar : function(){alert("d");}  }` and your point about the `60 times per second` how is that related to the code?

Comment: But i must write engine.event.fuct1(); funct2 funct 3 instead engine.event();

Comment: Ok for now it must be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want, the solution is convert your `events` property in your `engine` object into an object, like this:

```
const engine = {
    eventListeners:function(){
        window.addEventListener("resize",this.event.resize);
    },
    event:{ // You can have all your event methods here
        resize: function(){
            alert("d");
        },
        click: function(){
            alert("Clicked")
        },
        change: function(){
            alert("Changed")
        }
    }
}
engine.eventListeners();
```

**Look how it works:**

```js
let i = document.querySelector("input"),
    b = document.querySelector("button")
    
const engine = {
    eventListeners:function(){
        window.addEventListener("resize",this.event.resize);
        b.addEventListener("click",this.event.click);
        i.addEventListener("change",this.event.change);
    },
    event:{ // You can have all your event methods here
        resize: function(){
            console.log("Resized")
        },
        click: function(){
            console.log("Clicked")
        },
        change: function(){
            console.log("Changed")
        }
    }
}
engine.eventListeners();
```

```html
<input placeholder="change my value"/>
<button>Click me</button>
<h1>Try resizing your window</h1>
```

Comment: object is not like a function, ***I can't use all of event's function in one line*** for example if i want to create fuction foo I must write engine.event.foo() and for another functions same instead engine.event()

Comment: @WiktorJanecki That's exactly what the code I wrote does. You can call `engine.event.resize()`, `engine.event.click()` and `engine.event.change()`. Calling `engine.event()` while `event` is an object would be a fatal error in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

this.event is a function , you should return function from it and change it to this.event()

```
const engine = {
eventListeners:function(){
    window.addEventListener("resize",this.event());
},
event:function(){
    return function resize(){alert("d");}
},
```

}

Comment: It works for one function in event method but for more it doesnt

Comment: read question again , I editted it . I must use event 60 times per sec and inside event will be a lot of another functions

Comment: @WiktorJanecki why does it matter how many times this function is going to get called? You can call it as many times as you want... and if you want other functions to be called inside of the `event` function, then just do `function() { callFn1(); callFn2(); callFnn(); }`

Comment: when i want to do second event listener for second func in event it won't works

Comment: i dont think i follow, sorry